Buildup of testcontainers (and memory consumption) when using Singleton Containers
If we follow the recommendations outlined in A common misconfiguration of Singleton Containers, where we use @BeforeAll to start containers (instead of @Testcontainers, @Container, and @DynamicPropertySouce), the container instances created across multiple tests build up until all tests have been run, consuming a massive amount of memory. It is only after all tests have been run that Ryuk cleans them up via its resource reaper. Is there any way to configure Ryuk to remove each container at the end of every test class completion so that the testcontainers don't pile up and consume a massive amount of memory?
Also, if I add a @AfterAll method in my code to stop the container, I end up getting exceptions like the following in all tests that run after the first one. Subsequent tests try to connect to the port created for the first test. Can anyone explain why this happens and how to get around this limitation?
17:19:43.464 [sdk-async-response-3-33] ERROR i.a.c.s.l.s.AbstractPollingMessageSource - Error polling for messages in queue account-queue.
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: connection timed out after 2000 ms: /127.0.0.1:50818
    at software.amazon.awssdk.utils.CompletableFutureUtils.errorAsCompletionException(CompletableFutureUtils.java:65)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.AsyncExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.lambda$execute$0(AsyncExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:51)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(CompletableFuture.java:934)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniHandle.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:911)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2162)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.utils.CompletableFutureUtils.lambda$forwardExceptionTo$0(CompletableFutureUtils.java:79)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:863)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:841)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2162)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.AsyncRetryableStage$RetryingExecutor.maybeAttemptExecute(AsyncRetryableStage.java:103)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.AsyncRetryableStage$RetryingExecutor.maybeRetryExecute(AsyncRetryableStage.java:184)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.AsyncRetryableStage$RetryingExecutor.lambda$attemptExecute$1(AsyncRetryableStage.java:159)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:863)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:841)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2162)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.utils.CompletableFutureUtils.lambda$forwardExceptionTo$0(CompletableFutureUtils.java:79)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:863)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:841)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2162)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage.lambda$execute$0(MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage.java:108)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:863)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:841)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2162)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage.completeResponseFuture(MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage.java:255)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage.lambda$executeHttpRequest$3(MakeAsyncHttpRequestStage.java:167)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(CompletableFuture.java:934)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniHandle.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:911)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:482)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: connection timed out after 2000 ms: /127.0.0.1:50818
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException$BuilderImpl.build(SdkClientException.java:111)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException.create(SdkClientException.java:47)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.utils.RetryableStageHelper.setLastException(RetryableStageHelper.java:223)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.utils.RetryableStageHelper.setLastException(RetryableStageHelper.java:218)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.AsyncRetryableStage$RetryingExecutor.maybeRetryExecute(AsyncRetryableStage.java:182)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Request attempt 1 failure: Unable to execute HTTP request: connection timed out after 2000 ms: /127.0.0.1:50818
    Suppressed: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Request attempt 2 failure: Unable to execute HTTP request: connection timed out after 2000 ms: /127.0.0.1:50818
    Suppressed: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Request attempt 3 failure: Unable to execute HTTP request: connection timed out after 2000 ms: /127.0.0.1:50818

